# jQuery ui Accordion dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, append

I have an jQuery UI accordion.

in my html I only have a div declared

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

js

```
$("#mydiv").accordion();
```

I also have a function that creates the content of "mydiv"
Rendered html:

```
<h3>123</h3>
<div>content</div
<h3>456</h3>
<div>content</div
<h3>789</h3>
<div>content</div
```

the accordion does not work because if I look in my source the html is not changed what is normal. I used the .append method to add contend to "mydiv".
(I tried .html also)

Is there a better way to edit the html so the accordion will work as it should be. (Does javascript/jQuery have a stringbuilder like C#?)

UPDATE:

THE FUNCTION I USED TO ADD THE HTML TO MY PAGE

```
function GetSectionList(jsonurl) {
  $.getJSON(jsonurl).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.sections, function(sections, sectionItem) {
      $("#mydiv").append("<h3>" + sectionItem.name + "</h3>");
      $("#mydiv").append("<div><p>hello</p></div>");

      //$("#mydiv").html("<h3>abc</h3><div>test</div>");

      //Get article list
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr or jsbin with the code. Perhaps its a simple bug.

Comment: The rendered html is dynamic.  The data comes from some json calls. The structure of the rendered html is fine. I think the problem is that the html is rendered and not available in the source.

I have this in an each loop:

 $("#mydiv").append("<h3>" + object.name + "</h3>");
      $("#mydiv").append("<div><p>test</p></div>");

Comment: I made a fiddle and its working fine but also here the content is rendered fine in the source code.

http://jsfiddle.net/kr9gmthz/